# Mount grape framework in ramaze framework?

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, ramaze

Someone help me to mount grape framework...

```
require 'grape'

class Api < Grape::API 

    format :json 

    resources :articles do 
        get do 
            {hello: 'hello world!'}
        end
    end 

end
```

Also i wanna to change custom routes...